# mongoose: Add an element into an empty child array under

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, populate

I have the following schema, and I have a document of the story in mongodb, this story doesn't have values for key "fans", which is an array.
I would like to add an element to this array. However, I tried to use fans.push, fans.pop or fans = [element], it doesn't work. Please help me to understand what is the best way of doing this.

```
const personSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  stories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

const storySchema = Schema({
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
  title: String,
  fans: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
});

const Story = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

   const story1 = new Story({
     title: 'Casino Royale',
     author: author._id    // assign the _id from the person
   });

const fan = new Person({
  _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
  name:'Fan 001',
  age:38
});
fan.save(function(err){
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  const story1=Story.findOne({title:'Casino Royale'});
  story1.fans=[fan._id];
  story1.save(function (err){
    if (err) return handleError(err);
  });
});
```

when I run this script, I have got the following error:
[image]

Comment: You are not saving the story1 with Casino Royale where you write new Story, thus when you perform the findOne it should return nothing since there is nothing saved yet, try to console log that, then performing save on nothing is not a function xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here  `const story1=Story.findOne({title:'Casino Royale'});` findOne is not returning the document hence save is not defined for that.
as mentioned in the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-findOne)  it returns a query
try writing your code using promise and await for  the response

```
const story1 = await Story.findOne({title:'Casino Royale'});
```

Answer (score 1):

So to make this whole thing work you need a few steps:

Step 1: You need to save the story1 you created else the findOne wont return anything

Step 2: You need to await database calls since they are async

I will provide a code making use of the database update methods, it is a lot cleaner and faster to directly push it in the database.

So here is your code corrected:

```js
const personSchema = Schema({
            _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            name: String,
            age: Number,
            stories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
        });

        const storySchema = Schema({
            author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
            title: String,
            fans: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
        });

        const Story = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
        const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

        const author = { name: 'asdsd', _id: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" } // Note I hardcoded an id here

        const story1 = new Story({
            title: 'Casino Royale',
            author: author._id // Assign the _id from the person
        });
        await story1.save() // Await

        const fan = new Person({
            _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            name: 'Fan 001',
            age: 38
        });
        await fan.save(async function(err) { // Await since we have to await the database
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            const story1 = await Story.findOne({ title: 'Casino Royale' }); // Await database
            console.log(story1)
            story1.fans.push(fan._id);
            await story1.save(function(err) { // Await again
                if (err) return handleError(err);
            });
        });
```

Here is the code in a better version (Note that the schema doesnt have an _id anymore since it is provided by mongoDb):

```js
const personSchema = Schema({
            name: String,
            age: Number,
            stories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
        });

        const storySchema = Schema({
            author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
            title: String,
            fans: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
        });

        const Story = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
        const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

        const author = { name: 'asdsd', _id: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" } // Note I hardcoded an id here

        // Create a Story that is immediately saved in the database and gets an _id by mongoDb
        await Story.create({
            title: 'Casino Royale',
            author: author._id
        })

        // Create a Person that is immediately saved in the database and gets an _id by mongoDb
        const fan = await Person.create({
            name: 'Fan 001',
            age: 38
        })

        // Add the Person to the stories fans array
        const story1 = await Story.findOneAndUpdate(
            { title: 'Casino Royale' }, 
            { $push: { 'fans': fan._id } }, 
            { new: true })

        console.log(story1)
```